# Merge two arrays and apply a function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've two 3D numpy arrays:

- `M1` : shape `(x, y, z)` filled with value = val_x,y,z
- `M2` : shape `(x, y, k)` filled with value = val_x,y,k

Same size in both `x` and `y`, but different in the last dimension.

I'd like to build a 4D matrix `M` with shape `(x, y, z, k)` where value=val_1*val_2.

I've made a double `for` loop that do that but it's sub-optimal, is there any smart matrix operation to do that in numpy?

Comment: The close votes are justified. `value = val_x,y,z` is pretty much meaningless, as is `value=val_1*val_2`. You should really provide a minimal example of sample inputs and expected outputs. Providing your for loop implementation will remove any lingering ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Right now your dimensions are `(x, y, z)`, `(x, y, k)`. The ones on the left match, but you need to insert unit dimensions on the right to get them to line up to the output shape you want. The simplest way is to use [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis), which is an alias for `None`:

```
M1[..., None] * M2[..., None, :]
```

`...` means "grab" all dimensions not listed explicitly. It can appear at most once in an index. The first index is means grab `x, y, z` and add a new axis, so the resulting view is shaped `(x, y, z, 1)`. The second index means grab `x, y`, insert a new axis, then grab `k`, so the resulting view is shaped `(x, y, 1, k)`. The element-wise multiplication therefore results in a `(x, y, z, k)` array.